# Hiding navigation bar causes unexpected extra space in the bottom of the screen

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, monodevelop

I develop application both with WPF and GTK platforms using Xamarin forms. I decided to hide the default navbar using `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"`, but after that, I got an extra space at the bottom of the app window. On WPF everything works good, this bug occurs only in GTX platform.

It looks like this navbar became transparent and moved to the bottom.

Here is the link to the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrtlT.png

Comment: My colleagues described the same problem here, but the topics are still without a correct solution:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/86556/navigation-bar-causes-space-at-the-bottom-of-screen-in-ios
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74547/hidden-navigationbar-takes-space

Comment: Hi, could you show a capture of wrong page  , it will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking, I added the pic. It's an example that was made in paint, but the bug looks like that

Comment: It works in windows , not understanding bug in linux . You can detail Linux App means what .

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3153

Comment: Hi , thanks for sharing link .If found the workaround ,  you can update here in answer then mark it .

Comment: Sure, no problem

Answer (score 0):

> On Windows app everything works good, this bug occurs only in Linux app.

Not understanding occurs in **Linux app** .

By the way , if want to hide NavigationBar in forms , as follow will work :

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this,false);
```

Comment: I mean GTK# Platform

Comment: Yes, I know how to hide it. There is a problem with the side effects of this hiding

Comment: @RomanLarssen Got it , it's strange. Maybe this function not working in GTK# platform perfectly.